# Sms Delivery Recived Detection in Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, sms

I'm using the [mCore SMS Library](http://www.logixmobile.com/products/mcore/index.asp). I'd like to create a windows application and when i receive a delivery message, the application should save that information into a database.

- What technology can i use?
- Can i use windows services? How can i implement a windows service?

Comment: Can't you use it directly in your Windows App ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several questions you are asking so let's them split up a little:

- How to save delivery information in a Database File

  - To solve this problem you first need to know what kind of database you have (MS Sql, Oracle, MySql, etc.) For each of these exists some kind of DbAdapter. For e.g. the MS Sql you can take a look into the .net framework [System.Data.SqlClient Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t72t3k4.aspx).
- Can i use Windows Services?

  - This depends on the availability of your application and on what machine it will run. In a first step you can write it as a normal application. To get it later into a service you can take a look at [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx).

These are only very vague answer, but you only asked very vague. So dive in and if you good any concrete problems come back with a new question. ;-)